# Info.plist: Permission denied . Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 10

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, xcode10

I read new instructions in **Firebase & Fabric for Crashlytics** in Xcode 10.

Reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

> Xcode 10 only: Add your app's built Info.plist location to the Build
>   Phase's Input Files field:

I used

> "$SRCROOT/DemoProject/Info.plist"

But Getting issue at compile time.

> Info.plist: Permission denied . Command PhaseScriptExecution failed
>   with a nonzero exit code Xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently updated the firebase with Xcode 10. Google made it very simple as you just need to follow these simple steps:

1. Install the latest pods
2. Add new Run Script in your Target
3. Install the fabric mac app (Follow the instructions)
4. Add `$(SRCROOT)/Info.plist` (in My case) and make sure your .plist file in root folder. Just build + run..

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I did the following:

- Removed Firebase from my podfile
- Ran `pod install` (in the project directory)
- Deleted the pod and framework file from my project
- Added Firebase to my podfile
- Ran `pod install` (in the project directory)
- Cleaned the project folder
- Build

After these steps I was able to build successfully!

EDIT: Was missing steps 2, and 4!